# How to add picture in wxWidget's frame?

Tags: c++, widget, wxwidgets

I am very new to wxWidget. I want to create a frame which display some text and a picture. I had tried to search on internet/wsWidget help but I couldn't able to find the solution. I know there are some image hander like wxPNGHandler(); but I don't know how to use it. Any simple code to display the image will be very useful.

```
    class MyFrame : public wxFrame
    {
public:
     MyFrame();
    }

MyFrame :: MyFrame() : wxFrame( NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT( "My wxWidget" ), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize( 290, 180 ), wxCAPTION |  wxCLOSE_BOX)
{
  wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
  wxString  text = wxT("Text Display\n");
//Add image to display
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying for a day, finally this one worked.

```
wxPNGHandler *handler = new wxPNGHandler;
wxImage::AddHandler(handler);
wxStaticBitmap *image;
image = new wxStaticBitmap( this, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap("Windows_7_logo.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(50,100), wxSize(100, 500));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already found `wxStaticBitmap`, but the next time you have a question my advice is to search among the [wxWidgets samples](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/page_samples.html). For example, searching for `png` in all the `*.cpp` files under the samples directory would have found `samples/widgets/statbmp.cpp` which would have given you the name of the control to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

//Create a temporary (stack-allocated) wxPaintDC object
wxPaintDC paintDC(this);

//Draw Background image
paintDC.DrawBitmap(wxBitmap(wxImage("image.png")),0,0);